# Politics - singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, subjects

I am having difficulty deciding which of the following is correct:

> - Politics both *fascinates* and *repulses* him.
> - Politics both *fascinate* and *repulse* him.

I think, in part, this is because I am unsure if 'politics' is the subject.

Comment: The subject is *politics* (singular in this case). You might be interested in our sister site, English Language Learners; you can find it [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). It is helpful in answering basic questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That depends on what you want to say. If you are talking about politics in general, use the singular:

> Politics both fascinates and repulses him.

If, however, you are referring to specific politics, for example those of a person, use the plural:

> John's politics both fascinate and repulse him.

This is because *politics* can mean different things. The ones we care about here are (taken from the [online Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/politics)):

> 1a :  the art or science of government

and

> 4:  the political opinions or sympathies of a person

So, the first example is using sense 1a and the second is using sense 4.